Is the Passwords App really secure?
It appears to be great and very convenient but is it flawed?
It can be opened using the same lock code as the screen so all it takes is for a thief to watch someone enter the passcode before stealing the phone.
Is there a way to disable access via the screen lock passcode or ensure that it requires biometrics?

No, it is not possible to disable access via the screen lock pass code. If you long-press the icon for the app, you'll be able to select "Require Face-ID". However, if you fail Face-ID authentication twice, you can use the screen lock pass code to enter the app anyways.
Would I consider this flawed and insecure - not really. The pass code is generally used as a "trumps all" way to authenticate, since it can be used in place of Face-ID and Touch-ID, and it has been that way since the beginning of those features.
The way to use the phone in a secure manner given such a threat scenario - is to rely solely on biometric authentication when opening the phone in public (or anywhere the thief can watch you).

… and to use long passcodes/phrases for the iPhone
